# I want to calculate the mean of a pandas column for specific months

Tags: python, pandas

Let the df be with the columns `year`, `month`, `all time`, `daytime`, `region`, `temp`, and `precipitation` that contains data for several years and regions:

```
year  month alltime daytime   region        temp            precipitation
2000    1   True    False   saint louis 21.3105241935484  0.03
2000    1   False   True    saint louis 22.7246627565982  0.025
2000    1   False   False   saint louis 20.0136559139785  0.012
2000    2   True    False   saint louis 22.1646408045977  0.013
2000    2   False   True    saint louis 23.557868338558   0.07
2000    2   False   False   saint louis 20.8678927203065  0.012 
2000    3   True    False   saint louis 22.9311155913978  0.031
2000    3   False   True    saint louis 24.9204398826979  0.016
2000    3   False   False   saint louis 21.011541218638   0.0121
2000    4   True    False   saint louis 22.5921805555556  0.019
2000    4   False   True    saint louis 24.3710303030303  0.054
2000    4   False   False   saint louis 20.8877777777778  0.043 
2000    5   True    False   saint louis 21.4352016129032  0.032
2000    5   False   True    saint louis 22.8382404692082  0.023
```

I want to get a new df that contains the year and region as columns with calculated mean values for temp and precipitation for specific months (6th, 7th, and 8th month):

```
year  region            temp      precipitation
                                       
2000  saint louis     22.123      321.23
2000  diff region     24.643      673.12
2001  saint louis     21.433      134.27
```

I tried the following code:

```
a = weather.groupby(["region","year"]).mean("month")
```

But that gave returned the mean value of all 12 months:

```
region year month temp   prep
dakar 2000  6.5   24.788 0.028
      2001  6.5   23.533 0.032
```

Comment: Please edit your question in 2 ways:  i) make it reproducible, ii) give a desire output. More people will be encouraged to help in answering your question.

Comment: I tried posting the text here but it automatically changed it to image

Pls open it now

Comment: Yes, I edited the question @Mr.T

Comment: I voted to reopen the question. The task description is now clearer. However, what have you tried to achieve this? Please add your relevant code attempt with the specific problem you encountered.

Comment: hey @Mr.T. I posted what I tried !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter your dataframe by `MONTH` for the desired period using [Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html#boolean-indexing), [group by](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) both `YEAR` and `REGION`, then aggregate the mean for your categories like `TEMP` and `PRECIP`:

```
import pandas as pd

#fake data generation
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1234)
n=30
df = pd.DataFrame({"YEAR": np.random.choice([2000, 2001, 2003], n), 
                    "MONTH": np.random.randint(4, 10, n), 
                    "REGION": np.random.choice(["A", "B", "D"], n),
                    "TEMP": 20 + 10 * np.random.random(n), 
                    "PRECIP": 200 + 100 * np.random.random(n),
                    "OTHER": np.random.randint(1, 100, n)})
weather = df.sort_values(["YEAR", "MONTH",  "REGION"]).reset_index(drop=True)
#print(df)


new_df = weather[(6 <= weather["MONTH"]) & (weather["MONTH"] <= 8)].groupby(["YEAR", "REGION"])[["TEMP", "PRECIP"]].mean()
print(new_df)
```

Sample output:

```
                  TEMP      PRECIP
YEAR REGION                       
2000 A       29.870431  282.510453
     B       21.071268  255.776083
     D       26.612489  237.921426
2001 B       24.926556  236.412687
     D       22.292186  296.583653
2003 A       22.103778  271.091582
     B       29.121229  214.983372
     D       24.312329  241.211613
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing then is a subset of your data that will include only the months you need. Therefore,
You can create a new dataframe with the months you want to include, and then use `groupby.agg`:

```
months = ['6','7','8']
temp = df[df['month'].isin(months)]
res = (df.groupby(['region','year']).agg({'temp':'mean','precipitation':'mean'})).reset_index()
```

will give you:

```
        region  year       temp  precipitation
0  saint louis  2000  22.259055       0.028007
1  saint louis  2001  22.838240       0.023000
```

FYI, I added some extra data in my sample because in the data you posted you only have 1 year and 1 region.